# Inconsistency with small custom WebGL shaders under linux with Three.js

Tags: linux, three.js, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm experiencing some weird behavior with a relatively small custom shaders. This is the expected behavior as [seen under windows](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7-j_izzT1kTdUZ1WWNDMGJLazg&usp=sharing). Unfortunately under linux (you can see the files **warcluster-shaders-ubuntu** && **warcluster-shaders-archlinux** in the same folder) things are not so pretty :D In the **-ubuntu** video I've commented out on purpose gl_FragColor because it's too epileptic and difficult to pay attention what exactly is happening.
This is the code for the shaders:

```
var vertexshader = [

  "attribute float time;",
  "attribute vec3 color;",
  "attribute float aspect;",

  "varying float vTime;",
  "varying vec3 vColor;",

  "void main() {",
    "if (time != -1.0) {",
      "vTime = time;",
      "vColor = color;",

      "vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",

      "gl_PointSize = 12000.0 * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) ) * aspect;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;",
    "}",
  "}"
].join("\n")


var fragmentshader = [

  "uniform sampler2D texture;",

  "varying vec3 vColor;",
  "varying float vTime;",

  "void main() {",
    "float mid = 0.5;",
    "float angle = vTime;",

    "vec2 rotated1 = vec2(cos(angle) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) - sin(angle) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + mid,",
                         "cos(angle) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + sin(angle) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + mid);",

    "vec2 rotated2 = vec2(cos(-angle) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) - sin(-angle) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + mid,",
                         "cos(-angle) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + sin(-angle) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + mid);",

    "gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor , 1.0 );",
    "gl_FragColor *= texture2D( texture, rotated1 ) * texture2D( texture, rotated2 );",

  "}"
].join("\n")

var attributes = {
  time: { type: 'f', value: [] },
  aspect: { type: 'f', value: [] },
  color: { type: 'c', value: [] }
};

var uniforms = {
  texture:   { type: "t", value: this.context.resourcesLoader.get('/images/suns/sun_glow.png') }
};

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  uniforms:       uniforms,
  attributes:     attributes,
  vertexShader:   vertexshader,
  fragmentShader: fragmentshader,

  blending:       THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  depthTest:      false,
  transparent:    true
});

return shaderMaterial;
```

Do you have some tips where to take it from here? How to debug if the problem is in ANGLE, linux drivers or somewhere else?

This is my **chrome://gpu** info:

Graphics Feature Status

```
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash 3D: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
Compositing: Hardware accelerated and threaded.
Rasterization: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
```

Driver Bug Workarounds

```
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
init_gl_position_in_vertex_shader
init_vertex_attributes
use_current_program_after_successful_link
```

Problems Detected

```
Accelerated 2d canvas is unstable in Linux at the moment
Disabled Features: accelerated_2d_canvas
Stage3D is not supported on Linux: 129848
Disabled Features: flash_stage3d
Accelerated video decode is unavailable on Mac and Linux: 137247, 133828
Disabled Features: accelerated_video_decode
NVIDIA linux drivers are unstable when using multiple Open GL contexts and with low memory: 145600
Disabled Features: flash_stage3d, accelerated_video_decode, flash_3d
GPU rasterization is whitelisted on N4, N5, N7 and Moto X: 362779
Disabled Features: gpu_rasterization
Always call glUseProgram after a successful link to avoid a driver bug: 349137
Applied Workarounds: use_current_program_after_successful_link
Program link fails in NVIDIA Linux if gl_Position is not set: 286468
Applied Workarounds: init_gl_position_in_vertex_shader
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Linux NVIDIA drivers don't have the correct defaults for vertex attributes: 351528
Applied Workarounds: init_vertex_attributes
Disable partial swaps on linux drivers: 339493
Applied Workarounds: disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces
```

Version Information

Data exported     8/27/2014 9:26:08 PM

Chrome version    Chrome/36.0.1985.143

Operating system  Linux 3.13.0-32-generic

Software rendering list version   8.7

Driver bug list version   6.7

ANGLE commit id   b071b0f098e6

2D graphics backend   Skia

Command Line Args     --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

Driver Information

Initialization time   124

Sandboxed     true

GPU0  VENDOR = 0x10de, DEVICE= 0x0df2

Optimus   false

AMD switchable    false

Driver vendor     NVIDIA

Driver version    304.117

Driver date

Pixel shader version  4.20

Vertex shader version     4.20

Machine model name

Machine model version

GL_VENDOR     NVIDIA Corporation

GL_RENDERER   GeForce GT 435M/PCIe/SSE2

GL_VERSION    4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.117

Comment: The driver is pretty old. And nVidia sucks on Linux support. That's for sure. If I were You, I'd try updating the driver and/or trying [open source one](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/#nvc0familyfermi) (which should work too). Btw, according to [this](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/78469/en-us), Your GPU is still supported even on proprietary `340.46` version.

Comment: @Kamiccolo I tried with newer nvidia drivers 331 because 340 was too unstable and messed something. Unfortunately the problem didn't get away. We've put a live version of the problematic release on http://staging.warcluster.com in order to gather more information from playtesting. If you're using linux can you try the game and tell what are you experiencing :? Do you see some flashing lights after you login :?

Comment: nope, no flashing lights. Pretty stable output: http://i.imgur.com/4cujNCp.png

Using `nvidia-331-updates-uvm` (331.20).